# I still have not heard back from German Driving License Authority on converting my Canadian license and it's been 4 months!

Tags: germany, canada, driving-license

I attended an appointment in May at the Burgeramt in Berlin and submitted all information of my Canadian license for conversion to a German License under the mutual agreement.

I submitted all documents, eye test info, and the payment and was informed I would hear back by post when the license would be ready to pick up. What should I do ? I do not speak much German yet. Thank you!

Comment: Call them or go in person and ask for someone who can speak English?

Answer (score 2):

I contacted them and was directed to this link:

https://www.berlin.de/labo/mobilitaet/aktuelles/aktuelle-bearbeitungsstaende-736453.php

It tells you the date of applications they're currently processing. E.g I applied on May 24th and they're currently processing May 22nd applications.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask them; one way ot the other. Either by showing up onnce again in person of by sending them a letter. When sending a letter and kindly asking for the state of the affairs, you can possibly use the help of someone to write in German.

There is also a contact form on their website at https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/327537/standort/121646/. You can give that one a try first and once again possibly use the help of someone who writes German.

Make sure you include any "Aktenzeichen" (file reference) into the correspondence. You should find it on papers you got from them.